# FastAPI authentication for multiple services without managed API Gateway

Tags: python, authentication, jwt, microservices, fastapi

I have a general architectural question regarding a new project with microservices based on FastAPI. Looking at it now it’s really not FastAPI specific but here it goes:

How would you make JWT based authentication work between multiple services assuming the following:

1. You cannot use managed services from AWS etc. like API Gateway (security requirement)
2. There is a service for user management, which contains username, password etc. and ideally it would allow for JWT authentication
3. There are other microservices containing app logic for the users stored in the first microservice (from 2.)

In a monolith app this is easy and in a microservice architecture with API gateways it’s also easy but:

how would you approach this (high level) if things kind of hinge on the user management microservice to hold the relevant user data (and in effect being a gateway of its own) where other services should perform actions for those users (based on the JWT token)

tl;dr How would you extend authentication to the other microservices holding the app logic? I think I am overthinking this one and potentially introducing too much coupling :)

Comment: From an authentication perspective, what would be the difference of using your own user management service and a public API gateway as you call it? I would say the trick lies in developing the user management service to have the features you need, then the rest of the flow remains the same.

Comment: it's a security requirement - this project simply needs a user-based authentication and just having an API gateway is not enough. the microservices are the backend of a mobile app that should authenticate users first and then only display back information that their user is allowed to use/see. In a monolith you can just protect your endpoints and have JWT auth across all endpoints but with the user mgmt. now being in a separate service, it gets a little trickier

Comment: I understand, what I meant is that once you create your user management service, with all the security features you require, you can use it the same way you would use a standard API Gateway. BUT, I may not fully understand your use case. Please see answer below for a potential solution.

Comment: Yes, I am currently looking at Traefik w. ForwardAuth + my User Mgmt. Service as a solution. JWT is sadly only within Traefik Enterprise but since I am building my own service ForwardAuth might be ok. Do you have other open source alternatives? I think we are thinking in the same direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your authentication/user management service issues a JWT, then your other services can rely on that to provide only the allowed data.

The token issued should contain all relevant security info. Let's say you have three types of user: admin, manager, employee. For sake of simplicity let's say this is the only security criteria (you may have multiple criteria in place).

The token can have a field indicating the user permission. As per the [OAuth2](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/) spec this is usually done in a `scope` field.  You can create your own custom fields for it anyways.

With the token you can then call your backend services using it. The services will then:

- first check the integrity and validity of the token
- check the token payload for the scope/permissions and provide the data according to it.

See also the official [FastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/) about using scopes for this purpose with a simple dependency injection.

---

Answering your comment:

> JWT is sadly only within Traefik Enterprise

Maybe you're talking about handling the JWT directly in Traefik, but you should have no trouble passing on the authorization header and deal with the authorization check in the backend service. Plus, you can always embed the token in the request body and totally bypass the reverse proxy.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think the puzzle is almost complete. 1) Do you see any (bad) coupling issues regarding the scope? I mean in a way it's only an issue if the defined scope is too detailed/coupled in defining what users can see in each of the services. 2) the integrity/validity check would imply that all services can use the JWT secret correct?

Comment: 1) There's surely a certain amount of coupling involved, but I doubt you can avoid it. If you think about common authentication services (google, fb, etc), they also use scopes and you must comply with them so your app by definition must be coupled with their scope structure. It's like an API spec. Any two services communicating will have to use some common ground. 2) Yes. If you pass on the auth check to the services all of them must verify the token and the permissions, but with FastAPI it's really simple to do, just follow the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! Marked as answered